# lmdb no locks available error

Tags: python, lmdb

I have a data.mdb and lock.mdb file in test/ directory.  I was trying to use the python lmdb package to read/write data from the lmdb database.  I tried

```
import lmdb
env = lmdb.open('test', map_size=(1024**3), readonly=True)
```

but got the following error:

```
lmdb.Error: test: No locks available
```

Then I tried

```
mdb_stat test
```

with a separately installed lmdb library compiled from source and got the following error:

```
mdb_env_open failed, error 37 No locks available
```

However, in python I also tried

```
env = lmdb.open('test', map_size=(1024**3), lock=False)
```

This works and I can read data from the database normally.

I searched on Google about "lmdb no locks available error" very hard but got nothing.  Any one has any idea where this error came from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the -r option in mdb_stat to check the number of readers in the reader lock table. You may be hitting the max limit for number of readers. You can try setting this limit to a higher number.